# adding so files to code codenameone to native android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, codenameone, manifest

I am working on some new native packages to work with some special device , and the libraries used is (so) files , I would appreciate if some one can help me figure out how to include those files in the android build , I have tried adding the files in the native android folder but when trying to call the function from native , the following exception is shown :

```
10-29 14:10:07.610: D/BarcodeManager(6466): Barcode_Start()
10-29 14:10:07.610: W/System.err(6466): WARNING: Could not load library!
10-29 14:10:07.610: I/info(6466): error ===  Couldn't load Jctrl_gpio: findLibrary returned null
10-29 14:10:07.610: W/dalvikvm(6466): No implementation found for native Lcom/ctrl/gpio/Ioctl;.activate:(II)I
10-29 14:10:07.610: D/AndroidRuntime(6466): Shutting down VM
10-29 14:10:07.610: W/dalvikvm(6466): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41cd5300)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.ctrl.gpio.Ioctl.activate:(II)I
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at com.ctrl.gpio.Ioctl.activate(Native Method)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at com.POSD.controllers.ScanController.doScan(ScanController.java:715)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at com.POSD.controllers.ScanController.scan(ScanController.java:706)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at com.POSD.controllers.ScanController.Barcode_Start(ScanController.java:461)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at com.mycompany.myapp.NativePrinterImpl$ScanActivity.readBarCode(NativePrinterImpl.java:90)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at com.mycompany.myapp.NativePrinterImpl$ScanActivity.<init>(NativePrinterImpl.java:37)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at com.mycompany.myapp.NativePrinterImpl$1.run(NativePrinterImpl.java:130)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-29 14:10:07.620: E/AndroidRuntime(6466):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 14:10:07.620: W/ActivityManager(272):   Force finishing activity com.mycompany.myapp/.MyApplicationStub
10-29 14:10:08.160: W/ActivityManager(272): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{42681788 com.mycompany.myapp/.MyApplicationStub}
```

I am adding the native application that was included with the hardware log :

```
10-29 17:22:55.990 272-301/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.POS.apis/.ApiDemosMainActivity: +804ms
10-29 17:22:56.960 272-10680/system_process I/ActivityManager: START {cmp=com.POS.apis/.ScanController.ScanActivity u=0} from pid 11196
10-29 17:22:57.060 272-10680/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 91K, 15% free 9728K/11399K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
10-29 17:22:57.060 272-10680/system_process I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.908MB for 124216-byte allocation
10-29 17:22:57.090 272-10680/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 15% free 9844K/11527K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
10-29 17:22:57.140 11196-11200/com.POS.apis D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 887K, 15% free 8127K/9479K, paused 11ms+11ms, total 33ms
10-29 17:22:57.190 100-247/? I/AwesomePlayer: AwesomePlayer::AwesomePlayer()in
10-29 17:22:57.190 100-247/? I/AwesomePlayer: AwesomePlayer::AwesomePlayer()aftermClient.connect()
10-29 17:22:57.240 100-247/? I/FrameQueueManage: FrameQueueManage::~FrameQueueManage end!
10-29 17:22:57.290 272-301/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.POS.apis/.ScanController.ScanActivity: +192ms
10-29 17:22:58.270 100-246/? D/AudioHardware: AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
10-29 17:22:58.270 100-246/? D/AudioHardware: closePcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 1
10-29 17:22:58.300 100-246/? D/AudioHardware: AudioHardware pcm playback is exiting standby.
10-29 17:22:58.300 100-246/? D/AudioHardware: openPcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 0
10-29 17:22:58.310 11196-11196/com.POS.apis D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/data/com.POS.apis/lib/libJctrl_gpio.so 0x422fcf58
10-29 17:22:58.310 11196-11196/com.POS.apis D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/data/com.POS.apis/lib/libJctrl_gpio.so 0x422fcf58
10-29 17:22:58.310 11196-11196/com.POS.apis I/ctrl_gpio: JNI_OnLoad
10-29 17:22:58.310 11196-11196/com.POS.apis I/ctrl_gpio: native_activate fd=49,type=17,open=0
10-29 17:22:58.310 11196-11196/com.POS.apis I/ctrl_gpio: ret-------------0
10-29 17:22:58.310 11196-11196/com.POS.apis D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/data/com.POS.apis/lib/libserialport.so 0x422fcf58
10-29 17:22:58.310 11196-11196/com.POS.apis D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/data/com.POS.apis/lib/libserialport.so 0x422fcf58
10-29 17:22:58.310 11196-11196/com.POS.apis D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.POS.apis/lib/libserialport.so 0x422fcf58, skipping init
10-29 17:22:58.310 11196-11196/com.POS.apis D/serial_port: Opening serial port /dev/ttyS1 with flags 0x2
10-29 17:22:58.310 11196-11196/com.POS.apis D/serial_port: open() fd = 51
10-29 17:22:58.310 11196-11196/com.POS.apis I/info: open device!!
10-29 17:23:00.560 1997-1999/com.wandoujia.phoenix2.usbproxy D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 1233K, 39% free 9973K/16135K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 66ms
10-29 17:23:01.320 100-246/? D/AudioHardware: AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby.
10-29 17:23:01.320 100-246/? D/AudioHardware: closePcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 1
10-29 17:23:13.180 100-246/? D/AudioHardware: AudioHardware pcm playback is exiting standby.
10-29 17:23:13.180 100-246/? D/AudioHardware: openPcmOut_l() mPcmOpenCnt: 0
```

as you can see no problem loading the so file and the application works

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Just place the file inside the `Android` folder of your project `native` folder and you can use it in your native source code like that.

Comment: the files are in the same folder and [ I added the exception ]

Comment: try renaming the file to change its extension from `so` to `jar`.

Comment: it failed duing the build 
Could not expand ZIP '/tmp/build5780627911063745337xxx/MyApplication/libs/libN20Epp.jar'.

Comment: How about `.aar`?

Comment: aar actually works , in another application I used it and it works , but there are lots of (so) files that I need to include , I don't know how to create an aar that wraps the (so) files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157740/discussion-between-ahmad-abuiesa-and-diamond).

Comment: it seems that the same error :
* What went wrong: 
Execution failed for task ':prepareLibDecodeWltLibrary'. 
> Could not expand ZIP '/tmp/build5723516663095865157xxx/MyApplication/libs/libDecodeWlt.aar'.

Comment: I don't think you can rename an so to an AAR but I think you should be able to place multiple so files into a single AAR

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I already tried that , but same thing same exception can't load native library

Comment: @ShaiAlmog any ideas on how to fix the issue ??

Comment: I've never created an AAR file but I can try asking someone who has. I'm unclear on what isn't it working with multiple SO files for the AAR?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog , not that it is not working , ok I have followed steps on creating android library on android studio , and I have done assemble release that generates the aar file , and when adding it to the native directory , and do a build [ no problem so far ] , but when trying to use it in the code that call the native library I get the exception that is posted

Comment: Have you tried building the project with include source to troubleshoot this within Android studio using the debugger? If you can get that to work and can outline the changes you needed to make to the project we can see if there is a build hint missing https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I will try that and let you know what happens , thank you